# spring boot rest client connection Exception:: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null

Tags: spring-boot

while i am executing below code i am getting error like

`"org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null"`.
but when i use postman to call this "http://localhost:2018/test" it is working.

```
    static final String URL_EMPLOYEES = "http://localhost:2018/test";   
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] {  
             MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}));
        // Request to return XML format
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("replyMsg", "str");

        // HttpEntity<Employee[]>: To get result as Employee[].
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        // RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        // Send request with GET method, and Headers.

        ResponseEntity<String> response = 
       restTemplate.exchange(URL_EMPLOYEES,
                HttpMethod.POST, entity,String.class);

        HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
        // Status Code: 200
        if (statusCode == HttpStatus.OK) {
            // Response Body Data
            msg=response.getBody();
            if (msg != null) {
              System.out.println(msg);
            }
        }


//my clint controller class
    @RestController
    public class TextController {
   @RequestMapping(value="/test",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String myData2(@RequestBody String payload) {
   return "done";

 }  

   }
```

any suggetions?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jackson as your JSON parser, you can simply declare your parameter with the type [`TextNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode.html). This is the Jackson type representing JSON strings.

```
public String updateName(@PathVariable(MY_ID) String myId, @RequestBody TextNode name) {
```

You can then use its [`asText`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/TextNode.html#asText--) method to retrieve its text value.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are setting headers `Content-Type` with type `JSON` and passing the body of type `text/String`.

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON); //setting your Content type as JSON.
```

So, First you need to change this to

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN); //setting your Content type as Pure Text String.
```

and add some code after this line

```
// HttpEntity<Employee[]>: To get result as Employee[].
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
```

add this code

```
 // HttpEntity<Employee[]>: To get result as Employee[].
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        // RestTemplate
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        // Send request with GET method, and Headers.
        String entity_Str = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(entity);

        ResponseEntity<String> response = 
       restTemplate.exchange(URL_EMPLOYEES,
                HttpMethod.POST, entity_Str, String.class);
```

This might work for you.. Thanks :)